# C - How to sort false elements in array

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

A text file with names and results is put to a c program to be sorted by results. **How do ignore false inserts like number 8 in the file below?**

---

.txt code looks like this

Paul 35.6

Peter 53.4

Jack 23.0

8

Steph 0.0

Amanda 43.5

---

First array is arrayName[], second is arrayResult[], arrayFail[] is for 0.0 points.

```
#define ARRAYSIZE 15 // THIS IS THE MACRO FOR DEFINING THE ARRAY SIZE
#define STRSIZ 40 // THIS IS THE MACRO FOR DEFINING THE STRING SIZE

int main(){
    /* Declaration of variables */
    int i, j, n, f = 0;
    float a, m =0;
    char c;
    
    /* Defining the arrays for names and results */
    char arrayName[ARRAYSIZE][STRSIZ];
    char arrayTemp[ARRAYSIZE][STRSIZ];
    char arrayFail[ARRAYSIZE][STRSIZ];
    float arrayResults[ARRAYSIZE];
    
    n = ARRAYSIZE;
    
    /* Code to open file and check list for validation */   
    FILE *fp;
    
    fp = fopen("List.txt", "r"); //Opens the file
     
     
     while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
         if (c == '\n')
         m = m +1;
     }
     n = m;
    
    
    // Close the file 
    fclose(fp);
    
    /* Validates the name list */
    while( n <= 0 || n > 15){
        printf("\nThe list is invalid. It must be atleast one name and a maximum of 15 names. Please edit List.txt and re-run the program\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
    /* Here the program scans the list from the text file */
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%s %f", arrayName[i], &arrayResults[i]);
        
    }   
    
    /* Printing out the competitors list */
    printf("The competitors: ");
    
    for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
        printf("%s, ", arrayName[i]);
        
    }
    for(i = n - 1; i < n; i++){
        printf("%s.", arrayName[i]);
        
    }
    
    
    /* The array is ordered */
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
            if( arrayResults[i] < arrayResults[j]){
                a = arrayResults[i];
                strcpy(arrayTemp[i], arrayName[i]);
                arrayResults[i] = arrayResults[j];
                strcpy(arrayName[i], arrayName[j]);
                arrayResults[j] = a;
                strcpy(arrayName[j], arrayTemp[i]);
                
            }
        }
    }

    /* Printing out the Top 3 */
    printf("\n\nThe Top 3:\n");
    
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf("No%d: %s with %.1f\n", i+1, arrayName[i], arrayResults[i]);
    
        
    /* Failed competitors and their names are detected and stored */
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if( arrayResults[i] == 0 ){
            strcpy(arrayFail[f], arrayName[i]);
            f++;
        }
    }
    
    
    /* Printing out the failed competitors */
    printf("\nThe failed competitors were: ");
    for(i = 0; i < f - 1; i++){
        printf("%s, ", arrayFail[i]);
    }
    printf("%s.", arrayFail[f - 1]);
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to define what invalid input here means. As an example: a line must contain exactly 2 tokens delimited by space and the second token must be a decimal/number. Based on this, then you can work on the validation function.

Comment: What do you want to do with *invalid* lines? Put them at the beginning, at the end, leave them in place, remove them?

Comment: Remove them so that in the end when program is done sorting and prints the result it doesn't show "8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could test the validity of each entry during the collection and bypass it when the test fails (you could adjust the test to your own goal, here we just test that the string is not empty) :

```
int countEntry = 0;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    scanf("%s %f", arrayName[i], &arrayResults[i]);

    // If name or score is null, decrease i to ignore that entry
    if (arrayName[i][0] == 0 || arrayResults[i][0] == 0) i--;
    // Else counts the entry
    else countEntry++;
}
```

Then you should control that there is at least one valid entry :

```
if(countEntry == 0) {
    printf("\nThe list is invalid. It must be atleast one name. Please edit List.txt and re-run the program\n");
    return 0;
}
```